# Exchange 2010 + Sharepoint on single server

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, sharepoint-services

I seem to have the most unideal server setup so here we go:

**Situation:** 1 Server (2008 Std), Exchange 2010 (CAS + HUB) and Sharepoint Services 3.0 installed on it.

**Mission:** To get OWA working at: mail.systems.com and Sharepoint at, intranet.systems.net

**Execution:** you tell me how, becuase I do not know where to start :(

Shamil

Comment: I would strongly advise you not to do this.  And if only one server is availble to run the WSS instance in a VM.  I can only see endless headaches and downtime coming out of this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been advised not to do this, and henceforth, I abandon this attempt.

Comment: So you choose yourself instead of the guy who helped you... interesting ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really recommended as SharePoint tends to take over the .NET and IIS configurations and generally wreak havoc for non-SharePoint things. It can be done (see Small Business Server as proof), but it generally isn't worth the effort. Virtualize if you can, SharePoint web servers run great as a VM and you can host the SQL inside the VM for low traffic, or on your Exchange box or elsewhere if necessary.